# How can I load all my site menu and other textual content first and then load images in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using WordPress to create a website. When I load the page and check the network tab, my images are taking too long to load, which decreases my website speed.

So is it possible that I load other content, like my menu,page headings etc. And the load the images ?

Basically i want to improve my website performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you want to do is called "Lazy loading" of images.**

*Lazy loading* means that the images will be loaded "on-demand" rather then load with the initial load of your page, this will make your initial page load speed much faster if you have many images, or a few big images.

You could write your stand-alone javascript implementation.

But since you are using Wordpress, I would recommend you to look for a Wordpress plug-in that does just that and will be compatible with Wordpress right out-of-the-box.

Here is one option that i've found using a quick google search:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/lazy-load

You need to download the plug-in, install it on your Wordpress and activate it (and might also need to follow some instructions).

Plugin installation instruction:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/lazy-load/installation/

Plugin FAQ(with some code):
https://wordpress.org/plugins/lazy-load/faq/

Regarding lazy loading of content and menus, that is also possible and the concept is similar (loading resources after the initial page load is complete), If no Wordpress plug-in exists for this (I am sure there are a handful), you can do it with simple javascript using ajax.

Hope it helps a bit

Comment: Thanks and i did install that plugin, how do i configure this, I mean how to set the priority of loading ? will the plugin do it by itself ?

Comment: @Rajan enter plugin URL (given in my answer) click on the "Installation" tab and the installation instructions will appear, from what they say in the installation notes - once you installed and activated the plugin it should be ready to go

Comment: I have already installed so do i need to make any configurations  for this ? or will that plugin do that by it self ?

Comment: @Rajan please look at my answer, I have added a link to the plugin FAQ, which has some code in it. I have never used this plugin personally.